# No mapping exists from object type X to a known managed provider native type error while executing storedProcedure with ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

This is code:

```
   using (var con = GetWriteConnection())
            {
                int res = con.Exec(cmd =>
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title",Title));
                    cmd.CommandText = "AddTitle";
                    return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                });
                return res;
            }
```

there is no Title table.This is complex object. It is serialized to string(nvarchar(MAX)) by ServiceStack.OrmLite.
How can use ServiceStack's serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str=OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedValue(Title, typeof(Title));

str=str.SubString(1,str.Length-2); // (Clearing Quotes)
```

**UPDATE**  `Title.ToJsv()` does not work. Because there is "_type" in string.